# TikZ/PGF - \pgfarrowsdeclare deprecated?

Tags: tikz-pgf

While there are many references to `\pgfarrowsdeclare` in the Internet, this command is not described in the PGF manual (any more). What's the recommended way to defind your own arrow tip?

Comment: By the way, there is ***one*** occurrence of this command in the current manual. It is `\pgfarrowsdeclare{leaf}{leaf}`. However, I assume this is an oversight during updating. (I don't know where this is. I just know it is there because `pdfgrep` told me so.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\pgfdeclarearrow{<config>}
```

Page 1047.

Comment: Uh, section 100. That is far away from section 16, where I was looking.

Comment: @mhchem I used the index and just looked for `\pgfarrow...`. Then I went to that section and poked around a little ;).